# Android read json tag and assign to string

Tags: java, android, json

Hy guys,
i have develop a simple code to set in the action bar of my android app, a sub title. This sub title show the date when i read a specific json file wiht this code:

```
public String getSearchActionbarSubTitle()
{
    String subTitle = null;

    String s1[] = "json_address_file".split("=");
    if(s1.length > 2) {
        String s2[] = s1[2].split("T");
        if(s2.length>1) subTitle = "ultimo aggiornamento "+s2[0];
    }
    return subTitle;
}


public void setTitle(String title,String subTitle) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    getActionBar().setSubtitle(subTitle);
}
```

now i must be read in easy way a specific tag into this json file and assign the value to my String subTitle, so in the sub title into action bar appear the value of json tag.

Any help please?

Comment: Have read the documentation on [JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand your question.
But if you want to get the value of a json string you have to do something like:

`JsonString.getJSONObject(0).getString("TAG")`